# How can I tweak the numbering inside the appendices environment?

Tags: latex

I have the following structure in my Latex book:

1) main file

```
...
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
...
```

2) chapterN.tex

```
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\input{file3}

\begin{appendices}
\input{appendix_1_chapterN}
\input{appendix_2_chapterN}
\end{appendices}
```

The result is that the appendixes at the end of chapter 1 (for instance) is named ".1" and ".2", when I would like them to be name "1.A" and "1.B".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is covered in the documentation to the appendix package, which is required for the appendices environment that you are using: ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf

The answer to your question is that you are using the appendices environment for section appendices, where it is designed for chapter appendices. To achieve your goal of section appendices, use the subappendices environment instead as shown below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\section{Intro Sec}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Appendix Sec}
\end{subappendices}
Some Text

\chapter{Conclusion}
Some Text
\end{document}
```